# Updating GDB on mac osx 10.8 from 6.3 to 7.*

Tags: gdb, installation, osx-mountain-lion, uninstallation

I now have gdb-6.3 from Xcode. Wanting to upgrade to gdb-7.*

Here's what happened:
I used macports to install GDB-7.5, all is fine during installation only until I tried to run gdb as,

ggdb exectutable

it showed,

BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x2a
BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x28
BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x29
BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x2b
BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x2a
BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x28
BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x29
BFD: /Users/jiaxilong/Desktop/EECS281_proj3/proj2: unknown load command 0x2b

executable is compiled as,

g++ -ggdb a.cpp executable

i tried using -g as well. not working.

another thing is, gdb -v shows version 6.3
ggdb -v shows version 7.5

Please give a hand if you have a clue what i should do here :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like none knows the answer...or was it too trivial that the answer is apparent.
Anyway, I found the answer to this problem.

Basically, one can NOT yet install gdb 7.* on mac osx simply because mac has a stranglehold on this, probably because of its compatibility with xcode.

Wish i had known this earlier so that I had not put in tons of my time into researching and trying. But hopefully this can save those who are as bold and adventurous as I was.
cheers.

Comment: Actually.. I just found the answer... might be useful to you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336433/gdb-on-macosx-lion