# How to print out the content in vector<unique_ptr> with gdb on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, gdb, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use C++11 feature on Mac OS X. I downloaded g++ 4.8.1 with port.

This is the test code.

```
class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    A(A& a) {}
    A(int x) {this->x = x;}
    int get() {return x;}
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<A>> v;
    auto a = new A(10);
    unique_ptr<A> pa(a);
    v.push_back(move(pa)); // move(pa);
    for (auto& i: v)
    {
        cout << i->get();
    }
}
```

It compiles well under g++ 4.8, and I could debug it using gdb. Following [this page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF), I could print out STL vectors using `vector v` command.

However, with vector with unique_ptr, I got this error message in gdb.

[image]

```
Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete type "unique_ptr<A, std::default_delet
e<A> >", try casting to a known type, or void *.
```

What's the problem with it? How can I make unique_ptr complete type to get the content with gdb?

### ADDED

I noticed that clang++ in Xcode 4.5 supports c++11 features, so the easiest way might be to use Xcode. I have some issue with command line though ([lldb on xcode vs lldb on standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256800/lldb-on-xcode-vs-lldb-on-standalone))

Comment: Have you tried `($8)->get()`? It seems $8 is a pointer to a unique pointer...

Comment: @Kenny TM: Yes I have : "Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a struct or union" is an error message.

Comment: you may try using an Ubuntu virtual machine, I own a macbook pro but almost stopped developing for c++ in it. I put a Parallels Ubuntu instance fullscreen and forget about OS X :-). What's awesome, I got better font display from the Ubuntu VM than the native OS X (non-retina display) http://imgur.com/a/2DAvL

Comment: @chico - I think mac has stdc++ as default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972425/should-i-use-libc-or-libstdc

Comment: non-OSX specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798601/how-to-debug-c11-code-with-unique-ptr-in-ddd-or-gdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I could use Xcode; lldb works fine on Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

[Use python printers for GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2492341), your printers seem like deprecated stuff:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work (same print message) with my `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5` install from port. I also tested with gdb 7.6 install from brew, but it also doesn't work. I copied the .gdbinit in the debugging directory to make sure it is read.

Comment: @prosseek, it won't work with libc++, as your environment is OS X, I'm not sure whether you're using it. GCC python pretty printers support libstdc++.