# Can not install gdb on iMac with OS 10.8.6

Tags: c++, c, macos, gdb

I recently installed Eclipse to do some development on my Mac, but I realized that gdb is not installed (gcc and g++ are both installed).

I downlaod xcode but apparently gdb is not part of their command line tools (or at least it ws not installed in my case).

I also tried to dwonlaod gdb (version 6.3) and compile it locally. Everything seems to work fine, but when I run "sudo make install" i says that there is nothing to copy.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I can get gdb on working?

thanks for the help

Comment: That's a question for http://superuser.com

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19537327/556617